# iOS - play and download same video

Tags: ios, video, download

Is it possible to play a video in iOS when the MP4 video is being downloading. For example, the video has been downloaded 50% of its size, I don't want to wait to download the video after the other 50% is downloaded, can I just play the first 50% and then download the rest at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

YES.

You can use `AVPlayer` for this. Now `AVPlayer's SDK` is also available with lot of features. IT is [Here](https://github.com/iMoreApps/AVPlayer-for-iOS-Demo) with restricted license. `AVPlayer` use buffering to download and play side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is Possible Please check this code. 
You need MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h file in .h

```
-(void)PlayVideo
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]         initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:VideoUrl]];

    [Self.View addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    [moviePlayerController play];
}
```

Comment: @Tung Vo Please check this code. i hope this code you useful.